# Users address logic in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables in my laravel application `users` and `addresses` and both of them crud currently working, what i want to do is:

1. Set several address for each user (DONE)
2. Set Primary address (Ability of choose in order settings and profile page)

#### Question is:

Do I need 3rd table such as `address_user` to get user and address id or as it is now i just can add `primary` column to address table and let it be?

here is what i have:

`user` model

```
public function addresses(){
       return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
```

`Address` model

```
public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

`Address table`

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('postalcode')->nullable();
            $table->string('province');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

This is how i print data currently in users index

```
<td class="text-center">
  <ol>
    @foreach($user->addresses as $uad)
       <li>{{$uad->address}}<br>{{$uad->city}},{{$uad->postalcode}},{{$uad->province}}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ol>
</td>
```

[image]

## UPDATE

So base on suggestions I added column `is_primary` to my `addresses` table and I can set is to `0` and `1` in order to get users primary address, **BUT**

> Now I am in my user edit page and i have 2 address belongs to user
>   with id `1` now I want to change selected primary address to another
>   address but i am in user profile edit how do I update my address table
>   `is_primary` column while my form route is `users.update` and not `addresses_update` ?

## UPDATE 2

I've made some changes and here it is:

1. Users table have `address_id` column
2. Addresses table NO HAVE `is_primary` column anymore.
   *why? because user could set many address as primary! with this way user only can set 1 address as primary which will get id of that address.*

### Issue

1- I cannot get user primary address (don't know how!)

here is how i get user addresses:

```
@foreach($user->addresses as $address)
  <p>
    {{$address->address}}<br>
    {{$address->city}}, {{$address->province}}<br>
    {{$address->country}}<br>
    {{$address->postalcode}}
  </p>
@endforeach
```

But I'm not able to get user primary address.

Comment: You can still keep your address and just add new method called `public function primaryAddress() { return $this->address->where('is_primary',1) } `

Comment: @user2749200 I updated my question please take a look.

Comment: You pass the id of selected address and in your controller you set value of `is_primary ` 1. and save the address which should look like $user->address()->save($address);` FYI you might need to update first primary address `is_primary ` to 0 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

After adding `address_id` to my users table and getting address id as primary address here is how I get all my user's addresses and separate primary with others.

```
@foreach($user->addresses as $index => $address)
<tr>
 <td class="text-center">{{$index+1}}</td>
 <td class="text-center">{{$address->address}}</td>
 <td class="text-center">{{$address->city}}</td>
 <td class="text-center">{{$address->province}}</td>
 <td class="text-center">{{$address->country}}</td>
 <td class="text-center">{{$address->postalcode}}</td>
 <td class="text-center">
 <div class="funkyradio">
  @if($user->address_id == $address->id)
 <div class="funkyradio-success">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="yes" checked/>
  <label for="yes">Yes</label>
 </div>
  @else
 <div class="funkyradio-default">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="no"/>
  <label for="no">NO</label>
 </div>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Thanks to **Jonathon** and **Nemoden** for their helps (vote up) to them.

Comment: Hi @mafortis, What if we create a pivot table like the address_user. What is your thought on the same ?

Comment: @DurgeshPandey hi, it's the same thing in my case my table name was addresses and in your case table name is address_user but the logic is the same I guess. Ps: I strongly advise you to use plural names for tables such as addresses or you'll end up to setting table names statically in your models and further errors in future

Comment: thanks for correcting me on addresses_user. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Because `$user->addresses` will get you an instance of [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html), you can then filter that collection so as you want.

Example of `User` class method:

```
public function getPrimaryAddress(): Address
{
    return $this->addresses->where("is_primary", "=", 1)->first();
}
```

Of course you first getting ALL of the addresses which in most cases you do anyways.
If you want to issue a single query and get primary address you can still do so with just

```
public function getPrimaryAddress(): Address
{
    return Address::where('user_id', '=', $this->id)->andWhere('is_primary', '=', 1)->first();
}
```

But both of those imply you have `is_primary` column within `addresses` table.

Having `is_primary` in your `addresses` table would be beneficial if you want to get a list and check in a loop if that address is primary, e.g.

```
foreach ($user->addresses as $address) {
    if ($address->is_primary) { /* this address is primary */ }
}
```

To change primary address you need to set `is_primary` for the address which is already primary to `0` and set property `is_primary` of now-primary address to `1`.

```
public function setPrimaryAddress($address): bool
{
    if (is_numeric($address)) { // Should be PK.
        $address = Address::find($address);
    }
    $prev = $this->getPrimaryAddress();
    if ($address->id == $prev->id) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($prev->update(['is_primary' => 0])) {
        return $address->update(['is_primary' => 1]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, 1 more question here: when i use `getPrimaryAddress` in my user controller what should i use in my orders table to get this specific address and not others? or in my user profile to show him/her that this one is primary and other addresses are not? (sorry just want to be clear to me)

Comment: You are welcome. Answered to the question in the answer if I understood the question correctly :)

Comment: thanks man, i test it if works i will accept your answer if not i come ask again :)

Comment: Hey man, I have a question? Now I am in my user edit page and i have 2 address belongs to user with id `1` now I want to change selected primary address to other address but i am in user profile edit how do I update my address table `user_id` while my form route is `users.update` and not `addresses_update` ?

Comment: Updated the answer ^

Comment: where do i have to use this?! currently i do not have any `setPrimaryAddress` function anywhere!

Comment: That one would go to `User` class. I don't know if it works properly, but should be pretty close to be working otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have it so that one user can have many addresses but also that an one address can belong to many users then a many to many relationship using a pivot table like the `address_user` suggested would work fine. This is useful if you're trying to avoid duplicate data or you want to account for several people sharing an address.

As for allowing a user to have a primary address, you've got the right idea. Just add a column to your users table that points at their primary address in the addresses table and that should be it. If you go for the many to many approach you could add another field in the pivot table to flag an address as being the user's primary.

**Re: Update 2.**

With the changes you have made it should be quite easy to get the user's primary address. You have a few options. If you're looping through the user's addresses, you could simply compare the `$user->primary_address_id` (or in your case `address_id`) field to the `$address->id`:

```
@foreach ($user->addresses as $address)
  @if ($address->id == $user->primary_address_id)
    <p>Do something with your primary address</p>
  @endif
  <p>
    {{ $address->address }}<br>
    {{ $address->city }}, {{ $address->province }}<br>
    {{ $address->country }}<br>
    {{ $address->postalcode }}
  </p>
@endforeach
```

I would recommend adding a method to your `User` model to help you with this. Something like this would do the trick:

```
class User extends Model
{
    // ..

    public function isPrimaryAddress(Address $address)
    {
        return $this->primary_address_id == $address->id;
    }
}
```

That way you can replace `if ($address->id == $user->primary_address_id)` in the above template code with `@if ($user->isPrimaryAddress($address))`. That helps to keep your code more readable.

Now, if you wanted to, you could also add another relation to your user model to get your user's primary address:

```
class User extends Model
{
    // ..

    public function primaryAddress()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Address::class, 'id', 'primary_address_id');
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to get a user's primary address you just need to do this:

```
$primaryAddress = $user->primary_address;
```

Comment: `answer to first:` no i don't want give any public address to all my users, each user can have or have not their own address.   `To the second:` so you suggest i add column in my user table and not address table to get primary right?

Comment: In which case, you shouldn't need a pivot table and can stick with a one to many relationship. Personally, yes I would add a `primary_address_id` to the `users` table. Alternatively, you could add a `primary` column to the `addresses` table, but that would technically allow one user to have several primary addresses, so I would probably go with the former, dependent upon your requirements.

Comment: @mafortis Hi, I have updated my answer to answer your second question

Comment: Hi bro, well I tried user model ways it didn't work but I managed to get it done in other way. here it is  `@foreach($user->addresses as $index => $address)
{{$address->country}}
                            @if($user->address_id == $address->id)
primary
                            @else
not primary
                            @endif`

Comment: Hi @mafortis. Yes, I just used `primary_address_id` as it is more descriptive of what it represents, particularly to illustrate my point in my answer. That's why I wrote "`$user->primary_address_id` (or in your case `address_id`)" :)